# Cannot rerender text input inside react hooks form with pressable

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hook-form

Ive spent way too many hours on this.  I am using react hook forms with a react native app.  I have what should be a SIMPLE render to display a quantity field with a + and - minus to increment up or down.  The problem is that the text input NEVER updates.  There is no documentation for react native on how to do this.  Here is the relevant code:

```
const {
    control,
    handleSubmit,
    setValue,
    getValues,
    formState: { errors },
  } = useForm({
    defaultValues: item,
  });

  const onChange = (arg) => {
    const value = arg.nativeEvent.text;
    return {
      value,
    };
  };



 const renderQuantity = () => {
    return (
      <View style={[gridStyles.row, gridStyles.justifyCenter]}>
        <Pressable
          style={{ marginRight: 12 }}
          onPress={() => {
            if (Number.isInteger(quantity) && quantity > 0) {
              setValue("quantity", toString(quantity - 1));
            }
          }}
        >
          <FontAwesome name="minus" size={24} />
        </Pressable>
        <Controller
          control={control}
          render={({ field: { onChange, onBlur, value } }) => (
            <View
              style={[
                formStyles.input,
                errors["quantity"] && formStyles.errorInput,
              ]}
            >
              <TextInput
                style={[{ fontWeight: "bold" }]}
                placeholder="1"
                onBlue={onBlur}
                onChangeText={(value) => {
                  onChange(value);
                }}
                value={value}
                autoCapitalize="none"
                keyboardType="numeric"
              />
            </View>
          )}
          name="quantity"
        />
        <Pressable
          style={{ marginLeft: 12 }}
          onPress={() => {
            if (Number.isInteger(quantity)) {
              setValue("quantity", quantity + 1);
            } else {
              setValue("quantity", 1);
            }
          }}
        >
          <FontAwesome name="plus" size={24} />
        </Pressable>
      </View>
    );
  };
```

How the heck do I get the text input to rerender when changing values with the buttons?

Comment: The variable `quantity` which is referenced in a few places doesn't seem to be defined anywhere in scope. Was that missing in your snippet? We need to see that also. Theres a few other flags here but if you let me know about the code where quantity is define it would help.

Comment: @adsy sorry about that.  The quantity is an attribute in the `item` object that is passed as the control.  So `item = {quantity: 1}` for example.